# Is there size limit in csv writerow?

Tags: python, csv

I'm going to create a CSV of 1,341 rows (with header). In Python 3 I used the csv commands, but the created file has 1,282 lines

The row data was extracted from 1,340 PDFs of the metadata. I've created a list and a print to check, it's extracting everything right

The CSV code:

```
import csv

conjunto = open('emendas_autores.csv', mode='w', encoding='latin_1')

resultado = csv.DictWriter(conjunto, fieldnames=["Arquivo", "Autor", "Assunto", "Data_Criacao", "Data_Moficacao"])

resultado.writeheader()

def salva_csv():
    print("+")
    print (arquivo)
    print (author)
    print (subject)
    print (creation_date)
    print(mod_date)
    print("+")
    resultado.writerow({'Arquivo': arquivo,
                   'Autor': author, 
                   'Assunto': subject,
                   'Data_Criacao': creation_date,
                   'Data_Moficacao': mod_date})
    return
```

Then goes the iteration that extracts the data from the PDFs and calls the function `salva_csv ()` and each line

Please, would anyone know what could be wrong to stop at 1,282 lines? Is there size limit in csv writerow?

The complete code is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72DpG1W01nna3ZYNG5CeVI3VGc/view?usp=sharing):  (I warn you that it is a program that downloads many files)

Comment: You can now the limit with this command: csv.field_size_limit([new_limit])
Returns the current maximum field size allowed by the parser. If new_limit is given, this becomes the new limit.

Comment: Thank you. limit = csv.field_size_limit() / print (limit) / Shows 132072. Is this number 132,072 limit lines? But the CSV I want to create will be 1,341 rows

Comment: Yes, this is the number.

Comment: Thanks, I'll then test with the with mode that Alex Hall suggested below

Comment: Glade to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the CSV file when you're finished writing to it. Ideally use a `with` statement.